# get thumbnail image swap to fade

Tags: javascript, image, fade, swap

I'm just getting to throwing myself into the javascript, jQuery pool and have found some possible alternative solutions but I wanted to see if there was a way I could acheive fadeIn/fadeOut with the existing javascript I am using.

right now it is thumbnails that switch images in a main area onclick (actual site is onmouseover) using the following script:

```
    function switch_product_img(divName, totalImgs) {
        for (var i=1; i<=totalImgs; i++) {
            var showDivName = 'photo_' + i;
            var showObj = document.getElementById(showDivName);
            if (showDivName == divName)
                showObj.style.display = 'block';
            else
                showObj.style.display = 'none';             
            }
        }
    </script>
```

and there is a basic test you can see here: http://www.souldesigngroup.com/client/miguel/editorial/

I have tried multiple different ways to achieve it and have been given some suggestions but so far none of them have worked in any manifestation.  so any thoughts, suggestions, solutions would be greatly appreciated.

I know there are alternatives, and I may resort to rebuilding with one of them, but this is set up and working perfectly besides the fade.

thank you in advance for any help!
-soren

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use jQuery and do some modifications to your HTML, I have a solution for you.

**HTML**

```
<div class="photo" id="photo_1">...</div>
<div class="photo" id="photo_2">...</div>
<div class="photo" id="photo_3">...</div>

<ul class="thumbs">
    <li><a href="#" rel="photo_1"><img src="..." /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" rel="photo_2"><img src="..." /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" rel="photo_3"><img src="..." /></a></li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $('ul.thumbs a').click(function() {
        var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
        $('div.photo').fadeOut(500, function() {
            $('div#'+rel).fadeIn(500);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks Tatu, works great and the effect is there and I just need to work on positioning, etc...

but I noticed that there are 3 flashes of fade for each image, any idea what could be causing that?

thanks again